# How can I get images under a blog for a user

Tags: laravel, image, blogs, laravel-5.6

What I actually want is, for a specific user, I'm trying to show every image under a single blog. What I'm getting is a single blog post images for every blog.

**Controller**

```
$user_id = Session::get('id');
$user = Users::find($user_id);
$blogs = Blog::where('user_id', $user_id)->paginate(10);
$blogImage = BlogImage::where('blog_id', $blogs->pluck('id'))->get();


return view('Users.userlayout', compact('user', 'blogCat', 'blogs', 'username', 'blogImage'));
```

---

**View Page**

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <div class="post">

        @foreach($blogImage as $img)
            <img src="{{asset('storage/blog_img/'.$img->blog_img)}}" alt="Image"
                 class="img-responsive">
        @endforeach

        <p>
            <?php $str = $blog->blog_desc; ?>
            {{str_limit($str, 250, "...")}}
        </p>
        <a href="{{URL::to('/blog-details/'.$blog->id)}}" target="_blank" class="btn_1">
            Read more
        </a>
    </div>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you the code you in your models?

Comment: In those modes, I just added the tables name, nothing else. Cause I'm not that good to use models function like hasMany, belongsTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `where` instead of `whereIn`.

If you try and pass an array or a collection to `where` it will only use the first value.

```
$blogImage = BlogImage::whereIn('blog_id', $blogs->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Since this will return all of the `BlogImage`'s associated with the `Blog`'s the in the paginated list I would imagine you'll need to do a check to make sure you're only displaying the images that are associated with the specific `Blog`. One way you can do this is by using `[@continue()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops):

```
@foreach($blogImage as $img)

    @continue($blogImage->blog_id !== $blog->id)

    <img src="{{asset('storage/blog_img/'.$img->blog_img)}}" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">

@endforeach
```

---

All of that being said I would recommend using a [one-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) between `Blog` and `BlogImage`:

**Blog**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlogImage::class);
}
```

**BlogImage**

```
public function blog()
{
    return $this->belongTo(Blog::class);
}
```

Then in your controller you can [Eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the images and have something like:

```
$blogs = Blog::with('images')->where('user_id', $user_id)->paginate(10);
```

And your blade file would have:

```
@foreach($blog->images as $image)

    <img src="{{asset('storage/blog_img/'.$image->blog_img)}}" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">

@endforeach
```

You could then apply the same [one-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) logic between `User` and `Blog` as well.

Comment: sorry for a silly question, do I have to use this @foreach($blog->images as $image) under
@foreach($blogs as $blog)?

Comment: btw, Thanks, I guess I solved it with your help, thanks for your valuable time. btw in Blog::with('images') is that the function that i declared? or just passing the variable?

Comment: @Eyakub Yes, you would need to put  `@foreach($blog->images as $image)` under `@foreach($blogs as $blog)`. The `with()` method allows you to eager load your relationships so the `with('images')` will load the relationship defined in the `images()` method in your `Blog` class.